# Run a google standalone apps script for UI from the Script Editor

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a standalone Google Apps Script to implement a UI, with a doGet function.

I can deploy it, and access by a URL, and it works.

I can't see how/if I can test from the Script Editor. I can hit Run in the Editor, it executes the doGet script, but all that does is return an app object.

Comment: You can't debug the deployed script in the editor, although you can debug functions in your gs file(s) with the help of test functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing you can do at present is to click.

> publish (in the top menu) > Depoly as web app > Below the 'Current web app URL' you can select 'Test webapp for your latest code'.

This will open a browser tab with the current webapp while still not having to save a revision and publish.

The other option is the develop your UI in the context of a spreadsheet and call

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

But this has its obvious disadvantages.